# how to pass html form data to variable (nodejs / javascript)

Tags: forms, node.js, search

so i'm using nodejs and nodejsdb-mysql. i want to make form for adding and searching posts.
I make  html page with form, transform it to node using jsdom but how do i set up variables?
for example my html form is like:

name = text input
surname = text input
submit

and how do i pass inserted name/surname to var??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to turn your submit into a button with an event such as onclick - this might be what you are looking for:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="submit()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function submit(){
var name = document.getElementById('**name**').value;
var surname = document.getElementById('**surname**').value;
alert("Thanks for submitting, " +name);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for answering on such a short notice, however i'm not sure how to parse this into nodejs?? i put this code into indexhtml, create server using socket.io, node and nodedb-mysql but it doesn't really work hm..

Answer (score 0):

With nodejsdb-mysql sooner or later you will face real problems like date localization problems and so on, use https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql instead